# TCP/IP ACK sender: Transport layer or the app?

Tags: tcp, layer, transport

A newbie question: who exact send the ACK, the transport layer or the app? I have a COM-server with particle counters to send the data to my app. Sometimes I have a lost data. When I check the Wireshark protocol I see that the packets were sent from COM-Server but failed ACK from receiver. I think that ACK is missing because the my program has the error and can't edit the data properly. My colleague says that the interface (socket) simply gets no data and can't return ACK. Who is right?

Answer (score 3):

TCP is a transport layer protocol. The ACK is part of TCP. Thus the ACK is part of the transport layer and send there.

Note that there might be apps which include the transport layer (i.e user space TCP implementations) in which case the ACK is send by the app, but not in the application layer but still in the transport layer. But in most cases TCP is implemented in the kernel and is thus outside the app. See [OSI or TCP/IP model](http://www.vlsm-calc.net/models.php) for more information about these layers.

> My colleague says that the interface (socket) simply gets no data and can't return ACK. Who is right?

Assuming that you are not using a user space TCP implementation: The OS kernel will ACK the data as soon as these data are put into the socket buffer of your application. It will not ACK the packet if it failed to put it into the socket buffer, i.e. if the socket buffer is full because your application failed to read the data. In this case it will also reduce the window so that the peer will not send anymore data.

Comment: You should refer to the TCP reference model. The OSI model is defunct and doesn't refer to anything in the real world, let alone TCP, whose reference model precedes it in time.